# I'm trying to install fbprophet using pip on windows10 and the following error is showed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, data-science

I'm trying to install fbprophet using pip on windows10 and the following error is showed

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program
> files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;
> sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\ARJUNS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v9k4x_8v\fbprophet\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\ARJUNS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v9k4x_8v\fbprophet\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\ARJUNS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pjkjdpel\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

I have the pystan packet already installed

[image: The log image asked by phd]

Comment: Show the logs from full command output.

Comment: @phd I updated the image of log

Comment: Was the pystan installation successful? pystan has some pyx file that must be compiled. The pystan._api module that is imported during the setup of fbprophet is one of those pyx files.

Comment: Yes, pystan was successfully installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had faced same problem. I used "conda" rather than "pip" for installation with steps shown below and it worked magical for me.

step 1: conda install -c anaconda ephem

step 2:conda install -c conda-forge pystan

step 3: conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet

Now you can go ahead with : "from fbprophet import Prophet" in python environment.